# Как запустить React на сервере

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, сервер, reactjs

У меня есть фронтенд, часть на реакт и бэкэнд на *node*. Я через *ssh* загрузил все на сервер.

Как теперь сделать так, чтобы и бекенд и реакт загружались автоматом и работали сообща?

Я так понял, они в любом случаем будут на разных портах. Но как сделать, чтобы они запускались и работали всегда сами по себе? На данный момент запускаю `node server.js` и `npm start`.

Comment: Во-первых, надо сделать сборку npm build, во-вторых отдавать index.html с подключенной сборкой на клиент. А то у вас получается 2 сервера.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку где про все это почитать или напишите подробнее. Спасибо

Comment: даже не знаю пишет ли кто-то об этом, это же основы клиент серверного взаимодействия. Вы разрабатывали проект на локальном сервере, который запускался при помощи npm-модуля static-server. он просто отдавал вам файлы и ничего больше, если вам нужно на backend дополнительная функциональность, вы поднимаете сервер на node.js может быть при помощи фреймворков типа express, koa или sails.js и пишете вручную сервер, который так же отдаст файлы ( index.html + сборка, стили и пр. ) ну и пишете нужный вам функционал. [Посмотрите тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/327440/)

Answer (score 1):

Вам вебпак собирает бандлы для продакшена и эти бандлы подключаете в index.html и его отдаете через сервер на nodejs. Так что npm start запускать не надо, все зависимости будут уже установлены

Comment: Получается что react приложение это просто приложение что-то типа jqeury которое сразу все загружается на клиент и через ajax общается с backend?